# Conditional swapping of items in an array

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I have a collection of items of type A, B, and C.
I would like to process the collection and swap all A and B pairs, but if there is C (which is also a collection), I want to process that recursively.

So

```
#(A1 A2 B1 B2 A3 #(A4 A5 B3) )
```

would be translated into

```
#(A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 #(A4 B3 A5) )
```

The swap isn't transitive so `#(A1 B1 B2)` will be translated into `#(B1 A1 B2)` and not `#(B1 B2 A1)`.

I wanted to use `overlappingPairsDo:` but the problem is that the second element is always processed twice.

Can this be achieved somehow with Collection API without resorting to primitive forloops?

I am looking for readable, not performant solution.

Comment: Sorry, I don't yet understand what exactly the protocol is. As for `#overlappingPairsDo:`, have you considered using `#groupsOf:atATimeDo:` or `#pairsDo:`? Those will pass each item exactly once.

Comment: Protocol? The problem with `pairsDo:` is that it may skip: If I have `#(A1 A2 B1 B2)` then it will be paired as `#(A1 A2)` and `#(B1 B2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* my solution below should do what you're after, but a few notes up front:

- The "requirements" seem a bit artificial - as in, I'm having a hard time imagining a use case where you'd want this sort of swapping. But that could just be my lack of imagination, of course, or due to your attempt to simplify the problem.
- A proper solution should, in my opinion, create the objects required so that code can be moved where it belongs. My solution just plunks it (mostly) in a class-side method for demonstration purposes.
- You're asking for this to be "achieved somehow with [the] Collection API without resorting to primitive for[-]loops" - I wouldn't be so quick to dismiss going down to the basics. After all, if you look at the implementation of, say, `#overlappingPairsDo:`, that's exactly what they do, and since you're asking your question within the [pharo](/questions/tagged/pharo) tag, you're more than welcome to contribute your new way of doing something useful to the "Collections API" so that we can all benefit from it.

To help out, I've added a class `SwapPairsDemo` with two class-side methods. The first one is just a helper, since, for demonstration purposes, we're using the `Array` objects from your example, and they contain `ByteSymbol` instances as your `A` and `B` types which we want to distinguish from the `C` collection type - only, `ByteSymbol`s are of course themselves collections, so let's pretend they're not just for the sake of this exercise.

```
isRealCollection: anObject

^anObject isCollection
    and: [anObject isString not
    and: [anObject isSymbol not]]
```

The second method holds the code to show swapping and to allow recursion:

```
swapPairsIn: aCollection ifTypeA: isTypeABlock andTypeB: isTypeBBlock

| shouldSwapValues wasJustSwapped |
shouldSwapValues := OrderedCollection new: aCollection size - 1 withAll: false.
aCollection overlappingPairsWithIndexDo: [:firstItem :secondItem :eachIndex |
    (self isRealCollection: firstItem)
        ifTrue: [self swapPairsIn: firstItem ifTypeA: isTypeABlock andTypeB: isTypeBBlock]
        ifFalse: [
            shouldSwapValues at: eachIndex put: ((self isRealCollection: secondItem) not
                and: [(isTypeABlock value: firstItem)
                and: [isTypeBBlock value: secondItem]])
            ]
    ].
(self isRealCollection: aCollection last)
    ifTrue: [self swapPairsIn: aCollection last ifTypeA: isTypeABlock andTypeB: isTypeBBlock].
wasJustSwapped := false.
shouldSwapValues withIndexDo: [:eachBoolean :eachIndex |
    (eachBoolean and: [wasJustSwapped not])
        ifTrue: [
            aCollection swap: eachIndex with: eachIndex + 1.
            wasJustSwapped := true
            ]
        ifFalse: [wasJustSwapped := false]
    ]
```

That's a bit of a handful, and I'd usually refactor a method this big, plus you might want to take care of nil, empty lists, etc., but hopefully you get the idea for an approach to your problem. The code consists of three steps:

1. Build a collection (size one less than the size of the main collection) of booleans to determine whether two items *should* be swapped by iterating with `overlappingPairsWithIndexDo:`.
2. This iteration doesn't handle the last element by itself, so we need to take care of this element possibly being a collection in a separate step.
3. Finally, we use our collection of booleans to perform the swapping, but we don't swap again if we've just swapped the previous time (I think this is what you meant by the swap not being transitive).

To run the code, you need to supply your collection and a way to tell whether things are type "A" or "B" - I've just used your example, so I just ask them whether they start with those letters - obviously that could be substituted by whatever fits your use case.

```
| collection target isTypeA isTypeB  |
collection := #(A1 A2 B1 B2 A3 #(A4 A5 B3) ).
target := #(A1 B1 A2 B2 A3 #(A4 B3 A5) ).
isTypeA := [:anItem | anItem beginsWith: 'A'].
isTypeB := [:anItem | anItem beginsWith: 'B'].
SwapPairsDemo swapPairsIn: collection ifTypeA: isTypeA andTypeB: isTypeB.
^collection = target
```

Inspecting this in a workspace returns `true`, i.e. the swaps on the `collection` have been performed so that it is now the same as the `target`.

Comment: thank you for your exhaustive answer. I think that your initial points are perhaps most important here. Given how complex your solution is I think that I should take a step back and investigate my data structures. Because if this step is so overly complex, perhaps I should take a step back and solve or prepare the data earlier.

Comment: Glad you see it that way - often, having the right data structures for your specific business model will significantly simplify your solution because you can "abstract away" the underlying nitty gritty details so they don't get in your way. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution without recursion that uses a two step approach:

```
result := OrderedCollection new.
#(1 3 4 6 7) 
    piecesCutWhere: [ :a :b | a even = b even ]
    do: [ :run |
        result addAll: ((result isEmpty or: [ result last even ~= run first even ])
            ifTrue: [ run ]
            ifFalse: [ run reverse ]) ].

result asArray = #(1 4 3 6 7) "--> true"
```

So first we split the collection wherever we see the possibility for swapping. Then, in the second step, we only swap if the last element of the result collection still allows for swapping.

Adding recursion to this should be straight forward.